# What should the size of seekbar thumb's should be?

Tags: android, image, slider, seekbar

I am trying to put an image as thumb for my custom seekbar. The problem is I don't know what should the size of the image for the thumb be. In my case it just goes outside of the seekabr (too big).

Answer (score 0):

Check this, you will get idea about android's standard icon sizes

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html